# Sharing Core Data Between Apps. App Groups, iCloud

Tags: swift, core-data, icloud, cloudkit

I have two apps that I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to share data between.

- App 1 is a data logging app.
- App 2 is a data base app.

My goal is to have App 1 log some data, and then have it available in App 2, so it can be made relational to other data. Both apps use Core Data, and will use iCloud/CloudKit.

Is this as easy as setting both apps to the same iCloud ID? Do I need to figure out App Groups?

Comment: My understanding is the only way to share data between two apps is to use App Groups.

Comment: That was my original thought as well. But I believe there may be a way to share iCloud containers? Although I’m not sure how that works with the app itself? I haven’t been able to find a whole lot on the subject within the last 2 years. Or really at all.

Comment: I think you're right that multiple apps can use the same CK container.  "If you have a suite of apps, they can all share the same CloudKit container so users can have access to their data for all of your apps on every device they have associated with their iCloud account." ~ Gui Rambo: https://rambo.codes/posts/2020-02-25-cloudkit-101

Comment: Thanks Brian! It looks like CloudKit has everything I want to do. It seems figure out how to do it is the next step.

Comment: If you're only needing to share data between the devices of 1 user definitely go with NSPersistentCloudkitContainer (I haven't used this personally but it seems trivial to implement). If you need to share between users prepare to build your own very non-trivial implementation. I'm assuming at WWDC 2021 they'll roll out sharing with NSPersistentCloudkitContainer because that's the next logical step.

Comment: Hey Brian, Thats currently plan alright. I don't believe I need any sharing. To give a comparison, what I'm trying to do is take an app that logs data. (Say, like a list for groceries) and then have that data be shared with a different app. Say a food prep / recipes database. They both have their unique functions, but share a common goal. etc.